# Kibana Fields are not visible for different logs

Tags: field, logstash, kibana

am sending multiple logs to ELK stash which is visible in Kibana UI also in graphical format,
but the fields of all the logs are not visible. Only windows event log Fields are seen.

Can some one tell me what i have to do ??

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about the field list on the table ("Documents" for example with the sample dashboards), it's normal. This show only the fields for the logs on this table (by default 500 logs on time picked).

You can modify the pagging parameters on this field to show more logs (I tried 100 logs * 1000 pages without problem).

**Edit :** 
In the [kibana's documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/kibana/current/_table.html) it seems to exist the option you are looking for. Maybe by exporting the schema and putting this option? I will try later if I have time.

**Edit 2:**
I tried this and it works fine for me using some_dashboard.json on my server log. If don't know how to use json with kibana, look at [this documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/kibana/current/templated-and-scripted-dashboards.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using kibana4, it sounds like [this issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/1995).